# webpage issues on safari

Tags: jquery, html, css, safari

I have a webpage .that works all of the browers except safari. The dropdown select icon it has issues on Safari. I am attaching the link you can see this. I tried to fix the height of the select box but i cannot increase it. can you please help me out of this?

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/88666744/HTML/works/eak/products.html

see here in "CHOOSE YOUR SIZE"

```
    <style>
            .product_size_option .form-group .select-choice select {
  border: 1px solid #dcdcdc;
  border-radius: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 !important;
  height: 42px;
  width: 180px;
}
    </style>
```

if i increase the height here in SAFARi its wont work. 
Thank you

Comment: please give us some code to work with.

Comment: can you please check now. I have updated where I have problems

Comment: try adding this code to youe css.. for some reason safari has its own os styling.  -webkit-appearance: menulist-button;

Comment: where I need to put this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i was on the right track in my comment. it is the -webkit-appearance property but turn the property off like,

```
-webkit-appearance: none;
```

this worked for me in safari v5.1.7

update::

put it in your form-control class